# On Screen Off FCM loses the notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app is running I just screen off the device and no notification event is coming inside `FirebaseMessagingService`.

The notification is also not showing in the notification tray. Is that some bug with `FCM` or I am doing something wrong.

Please find attached code for `FCMService`.

```
public class FCMService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.createLogger(FCMService.class);

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
        if (null != message) {
            onNotificationReceived(message.getNotification(), message.getData());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     * @param data Notification Data
     */
    private void onNotificationReceived(RemoteMessage.Notification messageBody, final Map<String, String> data) {
        LOGGER.info("Notification received... for data %s", data);
        if (AppPreferences.getInstance().isUserLogin()) {
            if (null != messageBody) {
               LOGGER.info("Notification received... Foreground Notification...%");
            } else {
               LOGGER.info("Notification received... Silent Notification...%");    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are receiving the notification when your app is in the foreground then you should receive it when it is in the background. What device are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. You just have to set the `priority` to your message sent from you server and set it to `high`. In you server end add following key to the message:

```
"priority" : "high",
```

And notification start working at android end.

Answer (score 0):

Did you fire notification in app after getting message from firebase like

```
public void showNotification(String msg)
{
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

    // Build notification
    // Actions are just fake
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText(msg).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.original_logo)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.original_logo, "Call", pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.original_logo, "More", pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.original_logo, "And more", pIntent).build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // hide the notification after its selected
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

}
```

Comment: I don't understand what are you saying but I am not getting callback from firebase on onMessageReceived.