# Setting Fcm Notification Priority - Azure Notification Hub

Tags: azure, notifications

I am trying to set High Priority on an Fcm Notification Payload in C# SDK in order to send it the a mobile application from the Back-End.
Standing to the Fcm Documentation the Json Paylod should look like this:

```
{
  "message":{
    "topic":"subscriber-updates",
    "notification":{
      "body" : "This week's edition is now available.",
      "title" : "NewsMagazine.com",
    },
    "data" : {
      "volume" : "3.21.15",
      "contents" : "http://www.news-magazine.com/world-week/21659772"
    },
    "android":{
      "priority":"normal"
    },
    "apns":{
      "headers":{
        "apns-priority":"5"
      }
    },
    "webpush": {
      "headers": {
        "Urgency": "high"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Found here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=it)

In my code i tried diffent ways to do that with the Azure SDK.
**1**

```
var result = await voipClient.SendFcmNativeNotificationAsync(payload, tag);
```

Putting as payload this json

```
{
   "data":{
      "key":"value"   
},
   "android":{
      "priority":"high"

}
```

2

```
var notification = new FcmNotification(payload);
notification.Headers.Add("android", "{\"priority\": \"high\"}");
```

Putting ad payload the one i posted before

In both cases i receive the notification with normal priority.

Do you know where i'm making mistakes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at Azure Notification Hub documentation you could get confused because it links to FCM documentation: FCM allows different ways to build the payload, Notification Hub is stricter.

You should send the following payload:

```
{
   "data":{
      "key1":"value1",
      "key2":"value2",

   },
  "priority":"high"
}
```

The payload you send to Notification Hub is in fact the "android" field inside the Firebase payload.

**Note:**
The priority is set automatically to *high* by Notification Hub if you set the title inside the notification field as follow:

```
{
  "notification": {
    "title":"any title"
  }
}
```